# How can I import all databases from my development server to my local SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, import, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a development server `developSQL` where there are 5 databases. I want to copy all those databases to my laptop (local server).

How can I do this process without using backup files or there is only one option of doing backup files and using that backup file to restore how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can stop sql server, copy the all the mdf and ldf ( data and log files) and attach the copies to the sql server on your laptop
You can either attach them using a script or with management studio
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

Comment: I have actually used this technique during a disaster recovery when we lost the os but still had the disks. Attaching is much faster than a backup restore!

Comment: :How can i copy all the mdf and ldf files from the development server.

Comment: once the sql server service is stopped the files should be released so you would copy the files just as you would any other file. To locate the files of a particular database you can use sp_helpdb <dbname>; for example: sp_helpdb netshirt_represent_commerce